# Spark SQL : Truncate table is getting failed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute some commands on the Databricks platform to learn more about Spark SQL.I created a spark Dataframe from Pandas Dataframe and register that as temp view to execute sql queries. I am able to execute Select but not Truncate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create Pandas DataFrame
pd_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))

#convert it into Spark DataFrame
spark_temp = spark.createDataFrame(pd_temp)

#register Spark DataFrame as table to run sql query
spark_temp.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

#checking catalog list
print(spark.catalog.listTables())

**Output :**
(1) Spark Jobs
 spark_temp:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [0: double]
 [Table(name='temp', database=None, description=None, 
 tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```

Now, I can execute queries on this temp view :

```
# Now, query temp table
query = 'select * from temp'
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```

This is executing fine and I am getting output.
But, below execution is getting failed..

```
query = 'truncate table temp'
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```

***Output :***

```
"Table or view 'temp' not found in database 'default';"
```

But, we have that temp registered as view.

Comment: As the name `createOrReplaceTempView` this is view on top of a DataFrame. You cannot modify underlying DataFrame (it is immutable) hence truncate is not allowed. Which is similar to RDMS where you can not (usually) modify a view. If you want to remove it you can use `spark.catalog.dropTempView`

Comment: The error message is because spark tried to find a table in the database(in hive/impala if configured)